# AWS Translation - Excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, botocore

I have an excel file that contains multiple columns .The data inside it is in english language , I want to translate all of them into French(fr) and get the new excel ..

The problem is that `translate_txt` is not accepting dataframe , Is there any way to fix this ?

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd

translate = boto3.client(service_name='translate', region_name='us-east-1', use_ssl=True)

df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
result = translate.translate_text(Text=df,SourceLanguageCode="en", TargetLanguageCode="fr")
```

Comment: Does `df.apply(translate.translate_text, SourceLanguageCode='en', TargetLanguageCode='fr')` work for you?

Comment: I think not, but let me again give it a try.

Comment: If not - what errors/results do you get?

Comment: ` 

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 312, in _api_call
    "%s() only accepts keyword arguments." % py_operation_name)
TypeError: translate_text() only accepts keyword arguments.`

Comment: `df.applymap(lambda c: translate.translate_text(Text=c, SourceLanguageCode='en', TargetLanguageCode='fr'))` maybe?

Comment: `  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/validate.py", line 291, in serialize_to_request
    raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: ("Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid type for parameter Text, value: 0, type: <class 'int'>, valid types: <class 'str'>", 'occurred at index Unnamed: 0')`

Comment: Then amend it to only apply to text columns and not numbers....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178739/discussion-between-ronya-and-jon-clements).

Comment: It has only text ..

Answer (score 2):

I want to thank @JonClements for great help to fix the issue.

Solution provided by @JonClements worked -
`df.applymap(lambda c: translate.translate_text(Text=c, SourceLanguageCode='en', TargetLanguageCode='fr'))`

I was facing issues mostly with columns having ints and also `applymap` worked like charm.